# extract numbers from a string containing 3 numbers seperated by comas

Tags: php

I have this variable: `$pattern = "73,1,72";` //string in quotes

I want to create 3 new variables, first one should contain first value, second the second, and the third should contain the third.

So eventually should have these values:

```
$var1 == 73
$var2 == 1
$var3 == 72
```

How can I extract those numbers?

Comment: [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: are you sure about `==`?

Comment: not sure, but what after explode?

Comment: If you look in the manual you will see that after explode there is a  `(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) functions to achieve the desired result.

```
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = explode(",", $pattern);
```

Here's the demo, [**https://eval.in/836182**](https://eval.in/836182)

Answer (score 0):

```
$parts= explode(",", $pattern);
$var1 = $parts[0];
$var2 = $parts[1];
$var3 = $parts[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$pattern = "73,1,72"; 
$strings = explode(",",$pattern));
$ints = array();
for($i=0;$<count($strings);$i++)
{
   array_push($ints,intval($strings[$i]));

}
 $var1 =$ints[0];
 $var2 =$ints[1];
 $var3 =$ints[2];

?>
```

Comment: So you explode to an array, then you create a new array and for loop to push each element to this new array. Then you assign the values to the variables. The only question is WHY?

Comment: Because you want integers

Comment: PHP doesn't care if it's integers or not. `echo $strings[0]+$strings[1]` will output 74. https://3v4l.org/QHYlA

Comment: But if you want them as integers why not `$var = intval($strings[0]);`